# "Method does not override or implement" React Native movies example

Tags: android, gradle, react-native

I am running React Native Movies examples:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/tree/master/Examples/Movies

By running:

```
./gradlew :Examples:Movies:android:app:installDebug
```

I get this:
[image: Error screenshot]

For the standard MoviesActivity:

```
public class MoviesActivity extends ReactActivity {
@Override
    protected String getMainComponentName() {
        return "MoviesApp";
    }

  @Override // line 31
  protected @Nullable String getBundleAssetName() {
    return "MoviesApp.android.bundle";
  };

  @Override // line 36
  protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
    return "Examples/Movies/MoviesApp.android";
  }

  @Override
  protected boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
    return true;
  }

@Override // line 46
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
        return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
                new MainReactPackage()
            );
    }
}
```

Comment: The errors shown do not correspond to the code, i.e. the errors are on lines 31, 36 and 46, but at the very least, lines 36 and 46 don't exist in the code you show.

Comment: This is due to the fact I didn't include the imports. You're right, I've added comments explaining the line numbers.

Comment: Those methods don't exist in [ReactActivity](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/ReactActivity.java), so they can't be overridden

Comment: I think someone messed up a commit :D https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/49f20f41546e3ba8e7fe43c84c4c701684d0434d

Comment: You're right. Building succeeds after checkout out d78602b8cdb54a2097034ad06e81ae88a56033e0:
> git checkout d78602b8cdb54a2097034ad06e81ae88a56033e0

Comment: Somehow I couldn't imagine the examples wouldn't work because of a breaking commit and I guessed I did something wrong. Well, you live you learn...